# Why doesn't Sphinxsearch have easy documentation with easy examples like elasticsearch docs?

Tags: elasticsearch, sphinx

Sphinx is a good Full-Text Search tool for structured data and it's been existed since 2001 but on my idea, it doesn't have easy and full example documentation. Also, sphinx3.x setup and configs documentation is not easily accessible. Am I right? if then, anybody knows the reason behind it? 
Also, issues mentioned and discussed about it mostly in [sphinxsearch forum](http://sphinxsearch.com/forum) are not new in their date (mostly between 2010-2013/2015)

Comment: Well I think at the moment there is a single person behind sphinx, possibly not even doing as a 'full time' project (ie done in free time). Other projects might well have larger teams and/or communities.

Comment: Right. Elastic's marketing budget is tens of millions of dollars a year and the team is of about thousand members

Comment: I doubt that marketing budget is that important in this context. I think Sphinx is for kind small datasets - no clusters, no shards, no live update (I mean really well defined and efficient way to reindex datasets on the fly). Elastic on other hand is a part of BigData hyip. So Sphinx is a good tool but has no future :-( But still useful for some medium sized projects when there is search performance issue.